# Windsor FromAssemblyInDirectory Adding Assembly To Running Process

Tags: castle-windsor

I am registering components using Castle Windsor and the

```
Classes.FromAssemblyInDirectory
```

directive to load all the implementations of a service in a given directory. This works great. One of the features I'd like to add is to dynamically drop-in new assemblies to a running process (the process is a Windows Service.)

Now, my first thought is just to add a FileSystemWatcher and manually remove / register services whenever the files in the directory change. Which is fine, and I'm sure would work.

But before I wrote anything, it occurred to me that Windsor might have something like this already built-in. Which would be neat and save me some coding.

Googling didn't turn up anything obvious, but, well, I'm new to Windsor and do not perhaps know all the correct terminology.

Is anyone aware if this functionality exists?

Comment: I guess I'll assume "no, this isn't built in" for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not the kind of functionality that Windsor supports. It's not something IoC container is meant to do.